# developer portal in azure management api is not correctly working

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-management-api

[image]

Why it is that when clicking on API, it is displaying the popup as shown in the picture, rather then going to the API page?
I have publish the project and reset content but then also no change?
How can I activate the site?
It seems to me that some setting is still remaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You open the developer portal as [administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize#access-the-portal-as-an-administrator):

> Follow the steps below to access the managed version of the portal.
> In the Azure portal, navigate to your API Management instance.
> Select the Developer portal button in the top navigation bar.
> **A new browser tab with an administrative version of the portal will open.**

In this **administrative version** of the developer portal, you are able to modify the look & feel,...

If you want to use the [developer portal](https://mazhar444.developer.azure-api.net) as a usual user, you have to open the developer portal in a browser with private mode or with a different browser and sign in.